# Writing string with special chars to file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, special-characters

I am using a Ruby script to process some text files. Basically, reading each line, sometimes doing some manipulation and then writing the line to an output text file.

This works well, except when the original line has a new line `\n` character in there. In this case, the script will "execute" the new line instead of copying it literally.

**edit**

```
# output code:
modified_line # => "hello\nworld"

output.write(modified_line) # will output
hello
world

# output I am looking for:
hello\nworld
```

How can I make Ruby just write the string variable verbatim, ignoring any included special chars?

Comment: Can you show some code? The part that outputs to the text file.

Comment: Works for me :-) But seriously, Without seeing it, I have no clue why your code is behaving this way. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What answer do you hope to receive without showing your code? Show us your code.

Comment: That code is indeed minimal, but it is neither complete, nor verifiable. What is (the content of) `modified_line`, how does it end up in your `output` file and what is the expected output? What do you mean by _"the script will "execute" the new line"_?

Comment: How can the original line contain a second newline character if you are reading the file line by line? Maybe the file uses a different line separator or you are inserting newline characters instead of a literal ``\`` and `n`. Either way, you should try to fix the root cause instead of escaping the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do some `file.write(string_variable)`.

Use would want to use [String#dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-dump) which escapes all special characters. Like it says in the documentation:

> Produces a version of str with all nonprinting characters replaced by
>   \nnn notation and all special characters escaped.

So your code would look like

```
file.write(string_variable.dump)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: This notation may or may not match up with whatever expectations the receiving program has, so check that you're escaping correctly.

Comment: @Stefan I think with `execute` he meant that the line is split into a newline in the file at every `\n`

Comment: Indeed, the edit clarifies that. I've deleted my comment.